# Remove Polylines on a map from mapbox

Tags: javascript, mapbox, geojson

Does anybody know how I can remove Polylines that I have on a map. I hve tried many things to remove the lines taht is drawn up. But it will not dissapear. This is the code I used to draw the lines :

```
var geojson = [
  {
    "type": "Feature",
    "geometry": {
      "type": "LineString",
      "coordinates": [
        [10.39799, 63.43074],
        [10.3987, 63.431]
      ]
    },
    "properties": {
      "stroke": "#fc4353",
      "stroke-width": 5
    }
  },{
    "type": "Feature",
    "geometry": {
      "type": "LineString",
      "coordinates": [
        [10.397958755, 63.431],  
        [10.39868, 63.43073]
      ]
    },
    "properties": {
      "stroke": "#fc4353",
      "stroke-width": 5
    }
  }
];

L.geoJson(geojson, { style: L.mapbox.simplestyle.style }).addTo(map);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Store reference of the added thing to a variable. Then use `map.removeLayer`.

```
var layer = L.geoJson(geojson, { style: L.mapbox.simplestyle.style }).addTo(map);
map.removeLayer(layer);
```

https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox.js/api/v2.1.4/l-map-class/#map-stuff-methods

Comment: @Heikki  how to achive this in  android /java ?